# Codeeffects Linq Error: E106 The given ruleset does not contain any rules with type System.Xml.Linq.XElement

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

When I try to the following LINQ Filter

```
  var productsInfo = from product in productsElement.Descendants("product").Filter(rule)
                           from photo in product.Descendants("photo")
                           from parameter in product.Descendants("parameter")
                           let id = product.Attribute("id")
                           let addr = photo.Attribute("addr")
                           let name = parameter.Attribute("name")
                           select new { ID = id.Value, Addr = addr.Value, Name = name.Value };
```

I get the following error:

```
The given ruleset does not contain any rules with type
System.Xml.Linq.XElement, System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 (Error E106)
```

My rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><codeeffects xmlns="http://codeeffects.com/schemas/rule/41" xmlns:ui="http://codeeffects.com/schemas/ui/4"><rule id="09973a56-3d6a-4616-ae1c-40d0d17e95b9" webrule="4.3.6.7" utc="2017-07-24T10:07:08.6346" type="testSlimWebRule.products, testSlimWebRule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" eval="true"><definition><condition type="equal"><property name="AllProducts.product.id" /><value type="numeric">1</value></condition></definition><format><lines /></format></rule></codeeffects>
```

The XML:

```
 XDocument productsElement = XDocument.Parse(@"<products>
        <AllProducts>
             <product id='1'>
                 <photo addr='1.jpg'/>
                 <parameter name='name'/>
             </product>
             <product id='2'>
                 <photo addr='2.jpg'/>
                 <parameter name='Kenneth'/>
             </product>
          </AllProducts>
        </products> ");
```

The products class generated using Visual Studio "Insert as XML class":

```
namespace testSlimWebRule
{
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class products
{

    private productsAllProducts allProductsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public productsAllProducts AllProducts
    {
        get
        {
            return this.allProductsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.allProductsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class productsAllProducts
{

    private productsAllProductsProduct productField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public productsAllProductsProduct product
    {
        get
        {
            return this.productField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.productField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class productsAllProductsProduct
{

    private productsAllProductsProductPhoto photoField;

    private productsAllProductsProductParameter parameterField;

    private byte idField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public productsAllProductsProductPhoto photo
    {
        get
        {
            return this.photoField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.photoField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public productsAllProductsProductParameter parameter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parameterField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.parameterField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class productsAllProductsProductPhoto
{

    private string addrField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string addr
    {
        get
        {
            return this.addrField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.addrField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class productsAllProductsProductParameter
{

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}


}
```

The ASP.net part:

```
  <rule:RuleEditor ID="ruleEditor" runat="server"
                Mode="Filter"
                ShowToolBar="false"
                SourceAssembly="testSlimWebRule"
                SourceType="testSlimWebRule.products" />
```

I have tried several combinations of setting the filter, but just can't find a solution.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Filter()** extension takes a collection of objects and evaluates them against a given rule individually. The rule engine takes a type of an element of the collection and uses it to compile a lambda with a parameter of that type.

```cs
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
list.Filter(rule);
```

In this example the rule is of type *MyClass* and it gets applied to each object in the list similar to:

```cs
Evaluator<MyClass> ev = new Evaluator<MyClass>(rule);
foreach (var item in list)
{
    ev.Evaluate(item);
}
```

You may read more on CodeEffects documentation page: [Rule-Based Data Filtering Using LINQ to Object Provider](http://www.codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Linq-To-Object-Support).

In your example you made few mistakes:

1. You generate classes for XML elements, but don't use them.
2. The auto-generated classes incorrectly map the *AllProduct* field. It is supposed to be an array of *productsProduct*.
3. You apply a filter to a collection of *XElement* objects but the rule has type *testSlimWebRule.products*. It should be *XElement* in this case.

The example below will demonstrate four possible options, with the first one being the best.

### Main

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using CodeEffects.Rule.Core;

namespace testSlimWebRule
{
    class Program
    {
        /* Output:
         * Option A: 1, Bob, 1.jpg
         * Option B: 1, Bob, 1.jpg
         * Option C: 1, Bob, 1.jpg
         * Option D: 2, Kenneth, 2.jpg
         */
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                @"<products>
                    <AllProducts>
                        <product id='1'>
                            <photo addr='1.jpg'/>
                            <parameter name='Bob'/>
                        </product>
                        <product id='2'>
                            <photo addr='2.jpg'/>
                            <parameter name='Kenneth'/>
                        </product>
                    </AllProducts>
                </products>";

            XDocument dom = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            products products;
            //You need to load auto-generated classes. I prefer serialization. You may parse XML elements individually.
            using (var xmlReader = dom.CreateReader())
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(products));
                products = (products)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            }

            string productsProductRule = File.ReadAllText("rule1.xml");

            //A: Filter productsProduct[]; result is IEnumerable<productsProduct>.
            //This rule evaluates objects of the productsProduct type.
            var filteredProducts = products.AllProducts.Filter(productsProductRule);
            foreach (var product in filteredProducts)
                Console.WriteLine("Option A: {0}, {1}, {2}", product.id, product.parameter.name, product.photo.addr);

            string xElementRule = File.ReadAllText("rule2.xml");

            //B: Filter IEnumerable<XElement>; result is IEnumerable<XElement>.
            //This rule evaluates objects of the XElement type.
            var filteredElements = dom.Descendants("product").Filter(xElementRule);
            foreach (var element in filteredElements)
                Console.WriteLine("Option B: {0}, {1}, {2}", element.Attribute("id").Value, element.Element("parameter").Attribute("name").Value, element.Element("photo").Attribute("addr").Value);

            //C: Filter IEnumerable<XElement>; result is IEnumerable<'a> (anonymous)
            //This rule also evaluates objects of the XElement type.
            var productsInfo = from product in dom.Descendants("product").Filter(xElementRule)
                               from photo in product.Descendants("photo")
                               from parameter in product.Descendants("parameter")
                               let id = product.Attribute("id")
                               let addr = photo.Attribute("addr")
                               let name = parameter.Attribute("name")
                               select new
                               {
                                   ID = id.Value,
                                   Addr = addr.Value,
                                   Name = name.Value
                               };

            foreach (var info in productsInfo)
                Console.WriteLine("Option C: {0}, {1}, {2}", info.ID, info.Name, info.Addr);

            string anonymousRule = File.ReadAllText("rule3.xml");

            //D: Filter IEnumerable<'a>; result is IEnumerable<'a>
            //This rule evaluates objects of the anonymous type 'a with properties ID, Addr, and Name.
            var productsInfo2 = (from product in dom.Descendants("product")
                                 from photo in product.Descendants("photo")
                                 from parameter in product.Descendants("parameter")
                                 let id = product.Attribute("id")
                                 let addr = photo.Attribute("addr")
                                 let name = parameter.Attribute("name")
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     ID = id.Value,
                                     Addr = addr.Value,
                                     Name = name.Value
                                 })
                                .Filter(anonymousRule);

            foreach (var info in productsInfo2)
                Console.WriteLine("Option D: {0}, {1}, {2}", info.ID, info.Name, info.Addr);
        }
    }
}
```

### Auto-generated classes

You need re-paste your XML example to generate proper array fields. The one you have was generated with XML sample that only had one record. However to filter you need a collection.

```cs
using System;

namespace testSlimWebRule
{

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class products
    {

        private productsProduct[] allProductsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("product", IsNullable = false)]
        public productsProduct[] AllProducts
        {
            get
            {
                return this.allProductsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.allProductsField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class productsProduct
    {

        private productsProductPhoto photoField;

        private productsProductParameter parameterField;

        private byte idField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public productsProductPhoto photo
        {
            get
            {
                return this.photoField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.photoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public productsProductParameter parameter
        {
            get
            {
                return this.parameterField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.parameterField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public byte id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class productsProductPhoto
    {

        private string addrField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string addr
        {
            get
            {
                return this.addrField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.addrField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class productsProductParameter
    {

        private string nameField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### rule1.xml

This rule has proper type *testSlimWebRule.productsProduct*. It gets evaluated against each element in the auto-generated array of *testSlimWebRule.productsProduct*.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<codeeffects xmlns="http://codeeffects.com/schemas/rule/41" xmlns:ui="http://codeeffects.com/schemas/ui/4">
    <rule id="09973a56-3d6a-4616-ae1c-40d0d17e95b9" webrule="4.3.6.7" utc="2017-07-24T10:07:08.6346" type="testSlimWebRule.productsProduct, testSlimWebRule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" eval="true">
        <definition>
            <condition type="equal">
                <property name="id" />
                <value type="numeric">1</value>
            </condition>
        </definition>
    </rule>
</codeeffects>
```

### rule2.xml

This rule is the way you would have. It is applied to objects of type *System.Xml.Linq.XElement*. As such it can only operate on properties and methods of that type, i.e. you don't get your custom fields id, addr, name, etc.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<codeeffects xmlns="http://codeeffects.com/schemas/rule/41" xmlns:ui="http://codeeffects.com/schemas/ui/4">
    <rule id="e38da351-1190-47fb-b99b-d06787c9a459" webrule="4.3.6.7" utc="2017-07-24T10:07:08.6346" type="System.Xml.Linq.XElement, System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" eval="true">
        <definition>
            <condition type="equal">
                <property name="FirstAttribute.Value" />
                <value>1</value>
            </condition>
        </definition>
    </rule>
</codeeffects>
```

### rule3.xml

This rule does not have any type. Instead it receives whatever type it is evaluated against. In the example it gets anonymous type *'a*, so it can operate on properties ID, Name, and Addr.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<codeeffects xmlns="http://codeeffects.com/schemas/rule/41" xmlns:ui="http://codeeffects.com/schemas/ui/4">
    <rule id="7d72463f-5ae2-4617-a2bf-fd605fcb4f54" webrule="4.3.6.7" utc="2017-07-24T10:07:08.6346" type="" eval="true">
        <definition>
            <condition type="startsWith">
                <property name="Addr" />
                <value>2</value>
            </condition>
        </definition>
    </rule>
</codeeffects>
```